# Don't put yourself out, dear

Tags: logical-deduction, real

I asked my mother the other day, "What do you want for dinner? I'll get you anything your little heart desires."
My mother, true to form, radiated the stereotypical motherly vibe: "Don't worry about me. Just make whatever you want, dear."
So I said, "You want a nice cold-cut sandwich?" to which she replied, "I dunno, maybe something warm."
So I racked my brain. "How about some mac and cheese? You love my mac and cheese!"
She said "Maybe something meatier."
I said, "A steak? How about a nice, juicy steak?"
"Too much work, with the knife and the fork and the cutting and the chewing."
Hmm. "Spaghetti and meatballs? Meatballs are meaty!"
"Too round. Maybe something flatter?"

> What did my mother want to eat?

Comment: I may be just the only weird person, but what kind of person says: “I'll get you anything your little heart desires.” to their mother?

Comment: https://cooking.nytimes.com/recipes/12155-steak-n-bacon-cheddar-meatballs Hmmmmm...

Comment: Is this even a riddle really

Comment: No riddle tag. It's *real*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Perhaps

> she wanted a hamburger.  No cutting, meat, flat, warm.  But be sure to make the meat patties square.

Comment: There you go! I made Wendy's-style (square) hamburgers, which is what she wanted all along.

Comment: @Chowzen Are they small enough to eat without chewing?

Answer (score 9):

Not sure if I'm going at this the right way, but

> Meat loaf

Because

> It is very meaty, it is warm, it is usually not chewy(depends if your a good cook or not), and a piece can be flat-ish.