# What's that movie? (Geriatric Edition)

Tags: lateral-thinking, movies, real

**True story:**

My mother, 80 years old, asked me "What's that movie?"

"What movie?"

"You know, the one with that guy..."

"..."

"Run... Homer..."

"Homer Simpson?"

"No. Maybe. Was it Homer Simpson? Anyways, he started this restaurant, I think they sold chicken. Or maybe it was a warehouse..."

"..."

"You *know* this movie! He was in the army, and his best friend died."

I thought about the conversation for perhaps 15 seconds, then gave a guess.
"Was it {movie name}?"

I was right.

> Given the clues as I got them, can you also guess what movie she was referring to?

<sub>Many of her clues were wrong, but some of it is right.</sub>
<sub>This conversation is nearly verbatim as written.</sub>

Comment: Now we know where all your puzzles secretly come from!

Comment: @jafe Not all, just this one and [this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72350/dont-put-yourself-out-dear).

Comment: Aaaah, so _that's_ how one can circumvent Movies.SE's ban on story-identification :-)

Comment: @Chowzen seems that there is only one question (this) marked with the tag [tag:true]. Do you think that this is absolutely necessary?

Comment: @Glorfindel How about this?

Comment: Still feels like a [meta-tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/) to me, but definitely better.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Was it

> Forrest Gump?

Reasoning:

> Mention of "Run"

and

> Forrest and Lt. Dan sell shrimp (not chicken)

and

> Forrest's friend Bubba (for whom the Bubba Gump Shrimp Company is named) dies?

Answer (score 1):

I think it was:

> Good Will Hunting

"You know, the one with that guy..."

> Clearly Robin Williams

"Run... Homer..."

> The story he tells about the big game

"You know this movie! He was in the army, and his best friend died."

> He tells this story as well

"No. Maybe. Was it Homer Simpson? Anyways, he started this restaurant, I think they sold chicken. Or maybe it was a warehouse..."

> Ok, I guess not...  Huh...  Unless these were the details she was getting wrong?